# MMD Models Materials/Bones/Joints all Disappear and model becomes invisible

Tags: objects, bones, file-format, mmd-tools

I just opened blender so I can continue fixing another model unrelated to MMD, and decided to open one MMD Model for a reference then suddenly for no apparent reason the model loads in with nothing except a unusual outline of what its suppose to look like.
[image: The MMD Models corrupted?]

And This included nearly every single MMD Model I have in my computer except certain ones,
with the affected models containing absolutely nothing except the outline. Luckily any projects I had that contained the model didn't get the model affected. (although not that concerned since I have backups.)
[image: nothing in the model?]

The only assumption I have that may explain what happened to my models, is that a couple weeks back I needed space on my SSD for something I wanted so I decided to move some model folders to my HDD temporally then put them back to their original location on my SSD.

I guess that was a bad idea... so can anyone tell me what happened and how it happened here so A, This doesn't happen again to me, and B, If someone else accidently does the same thing I did they at least can google a possible fix and explanation here.

answer: mmdtools wasn't supported for 4.0 at this time so if this happens the tools arent ready for new version

Comment: Hey, recommended: if you solved the question, add the solution as an answer rather than an edit to the question.  (Alternatively: delete the question, it's fine, presumably the issue will disappear in a few days/weeks/months anyways.)